# Cannot read property 'products' of undefined in React app

Tags: json, reactjs, properties

I get the error Cannot read property 'products' of undefined for my web app. the code for the property is shown below

```
import React from 'react';
import ProductItem from '../product-item/ProductItem';
import Title from '../../common/Title';
import { useProductState } from '../../../global-state';

export default function ProductList() {
  // Accessing productState
  const { productState } = useProductState();
  const { products } = productState;
  let productItems = products.map(product => (
    <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} />
  ));
  return (
      <div className="py-5">
        <div className="container">
          <Title name="Our" title="Menu" />
          <div className="row">{productItems}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It seems that const { productState } hasn't been set. try share us with 'global-state' file'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are fetching data from some api? If so, maybe when `ProductList` mounts products are not fetced yet. Try this:

```
export default function ProductList() {
  // Accessing productState
  const { productState } = useProductState();
  const { products } = productState;

  if(!products) { // if products initial value is an empty array use !products.length
    return <div>Loading</div>
  }

  let productItems = products.map(product => (
    <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} />
  ));

  return (
      <div className="py-5">
        <div className="container">
          <Title name="Our" title="Menu" />
          <div className="row">{productItems}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```